# Nine patch images look pixelated

Tags: android, bitmap, nine-patch

I use several nine patch images in my layout, for buttons, text fields and form backgrounds. All of the *xxx.9.png* files are in the *drawable-hdpi* folder, just like the regular images, yet they still look pixelated.

[image]

The ImageView at the top has a regular bitmap and the lower ImageView uses a Nine Patch bitmap. You can see that the Nine Patch bitmap is scaled to a lower density. How do I fix that?

Comment: Ahave you tried exporting the image with longer height?

Comment: Could this be due to resolution limitations on the emulator/device your are using? If your lcd density is too low this might happen.

Comment: Then why would the image at the top be perfectly fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, it was messed up because I was calling *canvas.setDensity( 480 )* somewhere in a custom view. That caused this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should put 9 patch images in the nodpi folder, unless you want the non-stretchable area to be scaled/stretched also.

Comment: generally you do want the non-stretchy details in 9-patch images to be drawn cleanly, so you should provide a version for each supported density.